# Python appium scroll uiautomator

Tags: android, python, selenium, android-uiautomator, appium-android

Since i include

> Uiautomator2

```
appium.find_element_by_android_uiautomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains""(\"" + languages[i] + "\").instance(0))")
```

the uiautomator with scroll doesn t work.
The scroll made once, no more.